# Slow boot, main culprit is nmbd.service

Tags: boot, 20.04

Running Xubuntu, 20.04.4, with the OS on an SSD in a desktop machine.

Used to boot super fast, about a month ago noticed a huge increase in boot time.  Haven't made any major changes that I recall.

```
j@puter:~$ sudo systemd-analyze blame
[sudo] password for j: 
55.053s nmbd.service                                                           >
20.658s apt-daily-upgrade.service                                              >
11.846s apt-daily.service                                                      >
 2.054s upower.service                                                         >
 1.689s fwupd-refresh.service
```

My laptop, with which has 18.04.06 installed on a much slower cheaper SSD, (otherwise a very similar installation), shows just over 5s for nmbd.service, and apt-daily is not on the list.

So.... Main question is, how do I speed up nmbd.service?

Second, can anything be done about the 32 seconds spent on apt-daily?  My laptop seems to be getting by just fine, still getting the reminders about software updates (that **IS** what apt-daily does, correct?)

```
j@puter:~$ sudo systemctl status nmbd.service
● nmbd.service - Samba NMB Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nmbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-04-20 09:40:40 PDT; 1 day 23h ago
       Docs: man:nmbd(8)
             man:samba(7)
             man:smb.conf(5)
   Main PID: 1198 (nmbd)
     Status: "nmbd: ready to serve connections..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38297)
     Memory: 21.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nmbd.service
             └─1198 /usr/sbin/nmbd --foreground --no-process-group

Apr 20 09:39:45 puter systemd[1]: Starting Samba NMB Daemon...
Apr 20 09:40:40 puter systemd[1]: Started Samba NMB Daemon.
j@puter:~$
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `sudo systemctl status nmbd.service`.

Comment: The apt-daily job runs in the background, and should not delay boot at all. Nothing else during boot depends upon it. It will run at boot only if your daily random time has already passed. So sometimes it will run, sometimes it won't. It requires a working network connection.